# ListView row loses focus

Tags: android, android-listview, xamarin.android

I've got an issue where an EditText is in a row in a ListView.

The User can enter multiple lines of text in the EditText.  Each new line causes the Row to expand, and the ListView to refresh/update.

How can I:

- A) Prevent the list view from updating as a whole?
- B) Refocus the list view on the previous text view's position (the view gets recycled)
- C) A Better way?

I have tried:

- Subclassing ListView and setting the selection OnSizeChanged, OnFinishInflate, etc.
- Intercepting the EditText's Loss of focus and resetting list selection there.  (problem is the view gets recycled)

---

Currently Using:

- MonoDevelop 3.0.6
- Mono for Android: 4.4.55
- Android SDK: 4.0 (API level 14)

Answer (score 0):

Try playing with the [`DescendantFocusability`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#descendantFocusability) property on the `ListView`. I think setting it to `DescendantFocusability.AfterDescendants`, might solve your problem with the focus and resizing.

It works for my small sample:

MainActivity.cs

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace ListViewTests
{
    [Activity(Label = "ListViewTests", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class Activity1 : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            var lv = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView);
            lv.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Resource.Layout.ListViewItem, Resource.Id.textView, new [] {"1", "2"});
            lv.DescendantFocusability = DescendantFocusability.AfterDescendants;
        }
    }
}
```

ListViewItem.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

However you problem with views getting recycled will probably need some more work. You need to somehow save the state of the views and when they get created again restore the state. So for each item in your adapter you need to hook up to the events of your views. I.e. for `EditText` you want to hook up to either `TextChanged` or `AfterTextChanged` to get the text contained and save the state somewhere. This could be the item from the adapter you are displaying.